# I am passing a list from python to JavaScript in Flask, I want the output as Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

My python function:

```
def somefunction(self):
  x1 = ['reduced','fully automatic','years']
  return x1
```

In Flask app.py file

```
keyword = somefunction()
```

JavaScript in html:

```
<script>
var javaword = '{{ keyword }}';
somefunction {
alert(typeof(javaword));
alert(javaword);
}

----------
Output -
String
[&#39;reduced&#39;, &#39;fully automatic&#39;, &#39;years&#39;]
```

I want the output as

```
Object
['reduced','fully automatic','years']
```

---

## Solved

I figured it out and changed the following

```
var javaword =JSON.parse('{{ keyword|tojson }}');
```

Answer (score 1):

Three things. Firstly, you need to send it as JSON, not a Python string; secondly, you need to disable Jinja2 autoescaping for that variable; and finally, your JS needs to parse it from a JSON string to a JS object. So:

```
return jsonify(x1)
```

...

```
var javaword = JSON.parse('{{ keyword|safe }}');
```

Comment: thanks for your help but i figured it out . My Solution